# How to convert StreamReader to XDocument?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, streamreader, isolatedstorage

I am storing XML data in IsolatedStorage, while reading data from IsolatedStorage .I need to convert StreamReader to XDocument. 
Following code i have used to convert  StreamReader to XDocument. I am getting a error like : "root element is missing"

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {                   
                IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("AllHeadLine.xml", FileMode.Open);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoFileStream))
                {                        
                    displayXmlData.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();                       
                    XDocument offlineHeadline = XDocument.Load(reader);

                }
            }
```

EDIT : XML content

```
<category><catname>ರಾಜ್ಯ</catname><img>http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2013/3/2013_3$thumbimg113_Mar_2013_235853890.jpg</img><heading>ನನ್ನ ಮಗನ ಬಗ್ಗೆ ಹೆಮ್ಮೆ ಇದೆ</heading><navigateurl>some Url </navigateurl></category>
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: what does the xml look like?

Comment: Am getting XML data, i need to convert the StreamReader  to XDocument .@Jens Kloster

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at what you're doing:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoFileStream))
{                        
    displayXmlData.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();                       
    XDocument offlineHeadline = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

You're reading all the data out of the `StreamReader` via `ReadToEnd`, and *then* you're trying to load it into an `XDocument`. There's no more data to read! A few options:

- Read it to a string and then use that string to both set `displayXmlData.Text` *and* parse to a document with [`XDocument.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx). (If that's not supported on WP7, use a `StringReader` and `XDocument.Load`
- Get rid of the `ReadToEnd` call entirely, and live without setting `displayXmlData.Text`. It's not clear whether this was required or just for diagnostic purposes anyway.

Unless you really need the text of the file verbatim, I'd actually avoid creating the `StreamReader` at all, and load directly from the `Stream`. That will let LINQ to XML do the encoding detection too.

```
using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{                   
    using (var stream = storage.OpenFile("AllHeadLine.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        XDocument offlineHeadline = XDocument.Load(stream);
        ...
    }
}
```